# HDMI-CEC Android TV turn-off TV

Tags: android, hdmi, hdmi-cec

I have a Android TV box and I would like to use HDMI-CEC to turn on and off my TV, I'm using android shell commands to power on tv like: 'echo 0x40 0x04 > /sys/class/cec/cmd' and it works ok.

But when I use 'echo 0x40 0x36 > /sys/class/cec/cmd' to turn off tv and it no works, I need to know if I'm running bad this command to turn off tv or if I have to do something else different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Your "stand by" command is ok (works for me).
I just had to tune hdmi settings on both TV and device(tvbox) to reach the effect.
Generally it is strongly dependent on manufacturer...

Comment: Can you explain more ??

Comment: So how we can tune the HDMI settings in tvbox side ?

Answer (score 0):

Try 0xF0 0x36 instead of 0x40 0x36.

Get codes from here: https://www.cec-o-matic.com/ Looks like 0x40 is when source is "playback 1". If you set the source to "unregistered" the result code for standby is 0xF0 0x36. Worked for me on Android TV box with Samsung TV.

Comment: Not wokring ....